# onEdit(e) trigger doesn't work for me - Google Sheets, Google Apps Script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just tried to sort a column with names alphabetically once a new name is added or an existing name is edited (I started the sorting process from row two because row one is my header). I used the onEdit(e) trigger as shown. It should be a simple thing to do but it does not work. When I add a name to the sheet or edit an existing one nothing happens.

```
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nQZT16wiN9AX6FqZhioKyeLWoL7_BKfi09zRg");
sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function onEdit(e) {
  range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1);
  range.sort(1);  
}
```

The Spreadsheet looks like as seen in the picture:
[image: Sreadsheet]

I hope that someone has a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting spreadsheet in global scope:

```
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nQZT16wiN9AX6FqZhioKyeLWoL7_BKfi09zRg");
```

This requires any of the  [following scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)):

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

But simple triggers run without authorization[<sup>1</sup>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions).  Therefore, You cannot use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`. You could however get  the spreadsheet from the event object[<sup>2</sup>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) inside the onEdit:

```
const onEdit = e => e.source
  .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  .getRange("A2:A")
  .sort(1)
```

If you want to open any other spreadsheet than the current bound one, you'd need to use [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: Thank you. I just changed "openById()" to "getActiveSpreadsheet()" and now it works for me.